# Hive metastore Configuration with derby

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive, derby

In RedHat test server I installed hadoop 2.7 and I ran Hive ,Pig & Spark with out issues .But when tried to access metastore of Hive from Spark I got errors So I thought of putting hive-site.xml(After extracting 'apache-hive-1.2.1-bin.tar.gz' file I just add $HIVE_HOME to bashrc as per tutorial and everything was working other than this integration with Spark) In apache site  I found that I need to put hive-site.xml as metastore configuration
I created the file as below

```
<configuration>
<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
  <value>jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/metastore_db;create=true</value>
  <description>JDBC connect string for a JDBC metastore</description>
</property>
</configuration>
```

I put IP as **localhost** since it is single node machine .After that I am not able to connect to even Hive .It is throwing error

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:522)

....
Caused by: javax.jdo.JDOFatalDataStoreException: Unable to open a test connection to the given database. JDBC url = jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/metastore_db;create=true, username = APP. Terminating connection pool (set lazyInit to true if you expect to start your database after your app). Original Exception: ------
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/metastore_db;create=true

There are lot many error log pointing to the same thing . If I remove hive-site.xml from the conf folder hive is working without issues .Can anyone point me to the right path for default metastore configuration
Thanks
Anoop R

Comment: You could try to put echo $CLASSPATH command in the hive script.  But I have tried every suggestion on stackoverflow etc and get same error.  I am going to give up and try Spark or Hbase or something else.  Here is .bashrc:  `export HIVE_HOME=/usr/local/hive/apache-hive-2.1.1-bin
export PATH=$HIVE_HOME/bin:$PATH

export DERBY_INSTALL=/usr/local/derby/db-derby-10.13.1.1-bin
export DERBY_HOME=$DERBY_INSTALL
export PATH=$PATH:$DERBY_HOME/bin
export HIVE_CONF_DIR=$HIVE_HOME/conf

export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$DERBY_HOME/lib/derby.jar:$DERBY_HOME/lib/derbytools.jar`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Derby is used as an embedded database. try using

```
jdbc:derby:metastore_db;create=true
```

as jdbc-url. see also

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/AdminManual+MetastoreAdmin#AdminManualMetastoreAdmin-EmbeddedMetastore

To use the metastore fully functional (and by that to be able to access it from different services), try setting up using mysql as described in the document above.

Comment: You can use Derby in a server mode. See [HiveDerbyServerMode](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveDerbyServerMode).

Comment: I changed hive-ste.xml added that to conf folder.But now I am getting a different error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.ConnectException: Call From MTD-BORHTC01.inetservices.com/127.0.1.1 to localhost:9000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
Is there any thing removed or did wrongly from my end Thanks

Comment: The issue got resolved for hive after I restarted the hadoop with stop-all.sh then start-all.sh after that there was a safemode issue That also resolved using  hadoop dfsadmin -safemode leave command . I copied the file to spark conf folder .Still Spark shell is throwing warning  "16/02/05 07:52:11 WARN ObjectStore: Version information not found in metastore. hive.metastore.schema.verification is not enabled so recording the schema version 1.2.0
16/02/05 07:52:11 WARN ObjectStore: Failed to get database default, returning NoSuchObjectException
" What could be the issue with Spark conf

Answer (score 1):

As you are setting up an embedded metastore database, use the property below as JDBC URL:

```
<property>
   <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
   <value>jdbc:derby:metastore_db;create=true </value>
   <description>JDBC connect string for a JDBC metastore </description>
</property>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing similar kind of exception while installing hive. The thing which worked for me was to initialize the derby db. I used the following command to solve the problem : command -> Go to $HIVE_HOME/bin and run the command `schematool -initSchema -dbType derby`  . 
You can follow the link http://www.edureka.co/blog/apache-hive-installation-on-ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

It will work if you put derbyclient.jar in lib folder of hive